# LEFT JOIN to leftJoin() in Doctrine 1 - how to do it properly?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, left-join

I have two tables, `request` and `request_reply`, here is the `LEFT JOIN` query that selects requests along with the numbers of replies:

```
SELECT request.id, COUNT(request_reply.id) as replies
FROM request LEFT JOIN request_reply ON request.id = request_reply.request_id
GROUP BY `request`.`id`
ORDER BY replies ASC
```

But when I am trying to write it as a Doctrine query:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('Request.id, COUNT(RequestReply.id) as reply_count')
         ->from('Request')
         ->leftJoin('RequestReply ON Request.id = RequestReply.request_id')
         ->groupBy('Request.id')
         ->orderBy('reply_count ASC, Request.id DESC');
```

It comes out as without `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT `r`.`id` AS `r__id`, COUNT(`r2`.`id`) AS `r2__0` 
FROM `request` `r`, `request_reply` `r2`
GROUP BY `r`.`id`
ORDER BY `r2__0` ASC, `r`.`id` DESC
```

I don't understand what is wrong, I have tried everything, but there is no `JOIN` in the resulting query no matter what I do. And this is a legacy project with Doctrine 1, so I can't update to Doctrine 2.

**Update**

Mappings.

`Request.php`

```
$this->hasMany('RequestReply as Replies', array('local' => 'id', 'foreign' => 'request_id'));
```

`RequestReply.php`

```
$this->hasOne('Request', array('local' => 'request_id', 'foreign' => 'id'));
```

Comment: That's how it works in Doctrine, see the resulting SQL, it figures out which table corresponds to each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you mapped your entities correctly? I'd imagine that in your Entity Request you have a OneToMany annotation or anything else (YAML..) that points to the Entity RequestReply. If so, you should be able to achieve what you are looking for just doing this:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('Request.id, COUNT(rp.id) as reply_count')
         ->from('Request r')
         ->leftJoin('r.RequestReply rp')
         ->groupBy('r.id')
         ->orderBy('reply_count ASC, r.id DESC');
```

Let'me know if you got it working. Any doubt with the association mapping you can find [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

**[EDIT]**

Nick, Try again please. The first error was because I didn't know you had use a Alias Replies. Sorted out. The second error is gonna be gone with the field r.id in the SELECT. 
;-)

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('r.id, COUNT(rp.id) as reply_count')
         ->from('Request r')
         ->leftJoin('r.Replies rp')
         ->groupBy('r.id')
         ->orderBy('reply_count ASC, r.id DESC');
```

Comment: Updated the question with the mappings. With current scheme your suggestion produces the following error: `Unknown relation alias RequestReply`. If I change `hasMany('RequestReply as Replies')` to `hasMany('RequestReply')`, then it is `The root class of the query (alias r) must have at least one field selected`

Comment: I have tried what you're saying yesterday but without aliases `r`, `rp`, just with `leftJoin('RequestReply')` as it states in Doctrine docs - nothing, no `LEFT JOIN` in the resulting SQL. I seem to do it correctly but it just produces a simple select without `JOIN` in the end.

Comment: Damn, it worked: `string(191) "SELECT `r`.`id` AS `r__id`, COUNT(`r2`.`id`) AS `r2__0` FROM `request` `r` LEFT JOIN `request_reply` `r2` ON `r`.`id` = `r2`.`request_id` GROUP BY `r`.`id` ORDER BY `r2__0` ASC, `r`.`id` DESC"`. Thanks! Can you explain what did I do wrong?